# d3 Uncaught TypeError: zoomed.x is not a function

Tags: d3.js, tooltip, zooming

I am trying to implement tooltips and a zoom on a graph, the tooltips work fine however I am having issues with the zoom function. I get an error on the debugger that says: Uncaught TypeError: zoomed.x is not a function. This occurs at the line 'return zoomed.x(x);' I am not sure how to change the code to get it to work.

```
//Builder for REal time flow chart

define((function () {
    var categories = [
        {
            Name: "MediaServiceIndexes",
            Title: "Media",
            Style: "background-color:#ffffff;font-color:blue;",
            Text: "Here are the top media companies with whom our customers shop.",
            TitleStyle: "margin-left:0px"
        },
    ];

    var url = App.SiteUrl + "/Data/RequestDataFrom";
    var svg, width, numberChecker;

    var patterns = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range([
            "url(#blue1)", "url(#yellow1)",
            "url(#blue2)", "url(#yellow2)",
            "url(#blue3)", "url(#yellow3)",
            "url(#blue4)", "url(#yellow4)",
            "url(#blue5)", "url(#yellow5)"
        ]);
    var grayFill = "url(#gray)";

    var colors = d3.scale.category10();

    var getValues = function (values) {
        var result = [];
        try {
            values.forEach(function (item) {
                var o = {
                    Month: moment(item.month + "01", "YYYYMMDD"),
                    Value: parseFloat(item.change_in_market_share, 10)
                };
                var vendor = item.vendor.replace(/'/g, "");
                //var e = result.find(function (it) { return it.Vendor == vendor; });

                var e = false;
                for (var x in result) {
                    if (result.hasOwnProperty(x) && typeof result[x] != "function") {
                        if (result[x].Vendor == vendor) {
                            e = (result[x]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (e) {
                    e.Values.push(o);
                } else {
                    result.push({
                        Visible: true,
                        Vendor: vendor,
                        Values: [o]
                    });
                }
            });

            result.forEach(function (item, i) {
                item.Index = i;
                item.Values.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a.Month - b.Month;
                });
            });
        } catch (e) {
            result = null;
        };

        return result;

    };
    var createChart = function (chartElement, cd) {
        var chartData = cd; //chart data is being passed in using cd via createChart function 
        //chart gives the location of the chart, 

        var chart = function (el, data) {
            var margin = {
                top: 20,
                right: 180,
                bottom: 50,
                left: 110

            };
            var elem = el;
            var chartEl = chartElement;
            var fillData = [];


            var defs,
                gs,
                height,
                line,
                maxDays,
                minDays,
                minValue,
                maxValue,
                x,
                xAxis,
                y,
                yAxis;

            var initialiseData = function (dataValues) {
                minDays = d3.min(dataValues,
                    function (m) {
                        return d3.min(m.Values,
                            function (d) {
                                return d.Month;
                            });
                    });
                maxDays = d3.max(dataValues,
                    function (m) {
                        return d3.max(m.Values,
                            function (d) {
                                return d.Month;
                            });
                    });
                minValue = d3.min(chartData,
                    function (m) {
                        return d3.min(m.Values,
                            function (d) {
                                return d.Value;
                            });
                    });
                maxValue = d3.max(chartData,
                    function (m) {
                        return d3.max(m.Values,
                            function (d) {
                                return d.Value;
                            });
                    });
                console.log('min days: ' + minDays);
                console.log('max days: ' + maxDays);
                console.log('min value: ' + minValue);
                console.log('max value: ' + maxValue);

                dataValues.forEach(function (item) {
                    var nu = $.extend(true, {}, item);
                    nu.Values.push({ Month: maxDays, Value: minValue });
                    nu.Values.push({ Month: minDays, Value: minValue });
                    fillData.push(nu);
                });
            };
            //initialise scales
            var configSize = function () {
                if (isNaN(numberChecker) === true) {
                    numberChecker = $(chartEl).width();
                    width = numberChecker;

                }

                width = 750;

                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([0, width])
                    .domain([minDays, maxDays]);

                y = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([height, 0])
                    .domain([minValue, maxValue]);

                $('.adjustmentZoom .tick text').attr('y', '25');
                //initialise axis
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .tickFormat(function (d, i) {
                        if (Math.floor(d) !== d) {
                        } else {
                            return moment(d).format("MMM YY");
                        }
                    })
                    .orient('bottom');


                yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .tickFormat(function (d) {
                        return d3.round(d, 3) + "%"
                    })
                    .orient('left');

                $('#clipper rect').attr('width', width);
                $('.zoom-panel').attr('width', width);



            };
            var svgTransform = function(d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.Month) + "," + y(d.Value) + ")";
            };

            var zoomed = function () {
                svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
                svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
                svg.selectAll(".datapoint").attr("transform", svgTransform);

            };





            //the path generator for the line chart
            var initialise = function () {
                line = d3.svg.line()
                    .interpolate(
                        'cardinal')
                    .x(function (d) {
                        return x(d.Month);
                    })
                    .y(function (d) {
                        return y(d.Value);
                    });

                var zoomBeh = d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .x(x)
                    .y(y)
                    .scaleExtent([
                        1,
                        500
                    ])
                    .on('zoom', zoomed);



                //elem is window
                svg = d3.select(elem).append('div').attr('id', 'scatter').append('svg')
                    .attr('width', '100%')
                    .attr('height', '100%')
                    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 1000 550')
                    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
                    .append('g')
                    .attr("class", "line-container")
                    .attr('transform',
                        function () {
                            if (window.innerWidth > 650) {
                                var marginWidth = margin.left;

                            }
                            else if (window.innerWidth <= 650 && window.innerWidth > 549) {
                                var marginWidth = margin.left + 30;

                            }
                            else if (window.innerWidth <= 549) {
                                var marginWidth = margin.left + 50;

                            }
                            return 'translate(' + marginWidth + ',' + margin.top + ')'
                        }).call(zoomBeh);









                svg.append('rect')
                    .attr('class', 'zoom-panel')
                    .attr('width', width)
                    .attr('height', height)
                .call(zoomBeh);

                svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'x axis')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
                    .call(xAxis)
                    .selectAll('text');
                svg.append('text')
                    .attr('x', 400)
                    .attr('y', (height + 70))
                    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
                    .attr('class', 'xTitle')
                    .style('font-weight', '500')
                    .text('Date by month');
                svg.append('g').attr('class', 'y axis').attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)').style('text-anchor', 'end').call(yAxis);
                svg.append('text')
                    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
                    .attr('y', -100)
                    .attr('x', -200)
                    .attr('dy', '1em')
                    .attr('class', 'yTitle')
                    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
                    .style('font-weight', '500')
                    .text('Share prices in percentage');



                //zoom.scaleExtent([
                //    1,
                //    moment(maxDays).diff(minDays, "months")
                //]);


            }

            var tooltip = function () {
                svg = d3.select(elem)
                    .append('div')
                    .attr('class', 'tooltip')
                    .style('opacity', 0);
            };



            //draw calls drawData which will draw the lines of the chart
            var draw = function () {
                var drawData = function (dat, className, baseFill, area) {

                    //var selection (supermarket)
                    var supermarket, supermarketEnter;
                    supermarket = svg.selectAll('.' + className)
                        .data(dat,
                            function (c) {
                                return c.Vendor;
                            });

                    //var new selection (supermarketEnter)
                    supermarketEnter = supermarket.enter()
                        .append('g')
                        .attr('class', className)
                        .attr('data-vendor', function(d) { return d.Vendor; })
                        .attr('width', width)
                        .attr('height', height);
                    supermarketEnter.append('path');

                    //update new selection

                    supermarketEnter.attr('clip-path', 'url(#clipper)').attr('class', 'line').attr('id', function (d) { return d.Vendor; });

                    supermarketEnter
                        .selectAll("circle")
                        .data(function (d) {
                            return d.Values;
                        })
                            .enter()
                            .append('circle')
                            .attr('class', 'datapoint')
                            .attr('r', 4)
                            .style('fill',
                                function (d, i, j) {
                                    return dat[j].Visible ? baseFill(j) : grayFill;
                                })
                            .attr('transform',
                            function (d) {
                                return 'translate(' + x(d.Month) + ',' + y(d.Value) + ')';
                            })
                            .on('mouseover',
                            function (d, i, j) {
                                d3.select('.tooltip').style('opacity', '1');
                                d3.select('.tooltip')
                                    .html(dat[j].Vendor +
                                        '<br/> (' +
                                        moment(d.Month).format("MMM YYYY") +
                                        ', ' +
                                        d.Value.toPrecision(2) +
                                        '% )')
                                    .style('left',
                                        function () {

                                            if (window.innerWidth >= 1200) {
                                                var newWidth = d3.event.pageX -
                                                    ($(chartEl).width() / 2) +
                                                    'px'
                                            } else if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
                                                var newWidth = d3.event.pageX - ($(chartEl).width() / 10) + 'px'
                                            }

                                            return newWidth;
                                        })
                            .style('top', (d3.event.pageY) - 300 + 'px');


                            })
                            .on("mouseout",
                                function (d) {

                                    d3.select('.tooltip')
                                        .style('transition', '500')
                                        .style('opacity', 0)
                                        .style('color', d3.select(this).style('fill'));
                                });
                    supermarket.select('path')
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .attr('d',
                            function (d) {
                                return line(d.Values);
                            });

                    var path = supermarket.select('path')
                    .style('stroke', function (d, i) {
                        return (d.Visible ? baseFill(d.Index) : grayFill);

                    });
                    if (area) {
                        path.style('fill', function (d, i) { return (d.Visible ? baseFill(d.Index) : grayFill); });

                    }
                    supermarket.exit().remove();
                    supermarket.order();
                }

                svg.selectAll('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
                svg.selectAll('.y.axis').call(yAxis);


                drawData(chartData, 'supermarket', patterns, false);
                return zoomed.x(x);

            };

            var render = function () {
                configSize();
                draw();



            };

            //insertion of drawLegend into chart function so that this will draw as well as the lines of the chart.
            var drawLegend = function (dat, className) {


                //DATA JOIN
                //Join new data with old elements, if any.
                var supermarket, supermarketEnter;
                supermarket = svg.selectAll('legend_' + className)
                    .data(dat, function (c) { return c.Vendor; });

                //UPDATE
                //Update old elements as needed.
                supermarket.attr('class', 'update');



                //ENTER + UPDATE
                //After merging the entered elements with the update selection, apply operations to both.
                supermarketEnter = supermarket.enter().append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'legend_' + className)
                    .attr('data-vendor', function (d) { return d.Vendor; });
                supermarketEnter
                    .append('text')
                    .attr('class', 'supermarket-name')
                    .attr('data-vendor', function (d) { return d.Vendor; });//
                supermarket.select('text.supermarket-name')
                    .attr('x', width + 25)
                    .attr('y', function (d, i) { return (i * 1.25) * 20; })
                    .attr('dy', '.35em')
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.Vendor;
                    })
                    .on('click', function (d, i, j) {
                        dat[i].Visible = !dat[i].Visible;
                        var newOpacity = dat[i].Visible ? 1 : 0;

                        d3.select("[data-vendor='" + dat[i].Vendor + "']").style('opacity', newOpacity);
                    });
                supermarketEnter.append('rect')
                    .attr('class', 'supermarket-dot');
                supermarket.select('rect.supermarket-dot')
                    .attr('x', width + 10).attr('y', function (d, i) {
                        return ((i * 1.25) * 20) - 5;
                    })
                    .attr('width', 12)
                    .attr('height', 12)
                    .style('fill', function (d, i) {
                        return patterns(d.Index);

                    });

                //EXIT
                //Remove old elements as needed.
                supermarket.exit().remove();


            };





            //insertion of drawLegend into chart function originally placed after configSize(); draw(); };


            var toggleLines = function () {
                var dat = $(this.closest("g")).data();
                var obj = chartData.find(function (item) { return item.Vendor === dat.vendor; });
                if (obj.Visible) {
                    obj.Visible = false;
                } else {
                    obj.Visible = true;
                }
                chartData.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a.Visible === b.Visible) return 0;
                    if (a.Visible && !b.Visible) return 1;
                    return -1;
                });
                draw();
            };


            initialiseData(data);
            configSize();
            initialise();
            draw();
            drawLegend(chartData, 'supermarket');
            tooltip();


            $('.adjustmentZoom .tick text').attr('y', '25');
            return {
                Draw: render

            };


        };

        var c = chart(chartElement, chartData);
        //draw draws the lines of the chart. chart function draws the space arou
        $(window).on("resize", function () {
            c.Draw();
            $('.adjustmentZoom .tick text').attr('y', '25');
        });

    }




    var initialiseElement = function () {
        categories.forEach(function (item) {
            $(".slidesIntroduction").append('<div class="">\
                    <div class="insight-chart chart tradingData ' + item.Name + '" style="' + item.Style + '">\
                    <h3 class="chartTitle" ><br />\All ' + item.Title + '</h3>\
                        <p style="' + item.TitleStyle + '">\
                            <br />\
                            ' + item.Text + '\
                        </p>\
                    </div>\
                <//div>');
        });
    };



    var renderInsightData = function () {
        initialiseElement();
        categories.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.DataValues) {
                createChart("." + item.Name, item.DataValues);
            }
        });
    };

    var startWork = function () {
        var catCount = 0;

        var startRequest = function () {
            App.Modules.ServerComms.PollForData({
                Url: url,
                Data: { src: categories[catCount].Name },
                Success: processResponse,
            });
        };

        var processResponse = function (response) {
            categories[catCount].DataValues = getValues(response);
            catCount++;
            if (catCount < categories.length) {
                startRequest();
            } else {
                renderInsightData();
                $(".spinner").removeClass("spinner");
            }
        };

        startRequest();
    };

    return {
        Name: "Introduction",
        Init: function () { },
        Start: startWork
    }

})());
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do with that line of code?  `zoomed` is a function, it has no child function of `x`?

Comment: hoping to zoom via the x axis, zoomBeh has the child function. I have just tried swapping the function in the return statement however I am getting an Uncaught Reference Error.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Builder for REal time flow chart

define((function () {
    var categories = [
        {
            Name: "MediaServiceIndexes",
            Title: "Media",
            Style: "background-color:#ffffff;font-color:blue;",
            Text: "Here are the top media companies with whom our customers shop.",
            TitleStyle: "margin-left:0px"
        },
    ];

    var url = App.SiteUrl + "/Data/RequestDataFrom";
    var svg, width, numberChecker;

    var patterns = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range([
            "url(#blue1)", "url(#yellow1)",
            "url(#blue2)", "url(#yellow2)",
            "url(#blue3)", "url(#yellow3)",
            "url(#blue4)", "url(#yellow4)",
            "url(#blue5)", "url(#yellow5)"
        ]);
    var grayFill = "url(#gray)";

    var colors = d3.scale.category10();

    var getValues = function (values) {
        var result = [];
        try {
            values.forEach(function (item) {
                var o = {
                    Month: moment(item.month + "01", "YYYYMMDD"),
                    Value: parseFloat(item.change_in_market_share, 10)
                };
                var vendor = item.vendor.replace(/'/g, "");
                //var e = result.find(function (it) { return it.Vendor == vendor; });

                var e = false;
                for (var x in result) {
                    if (result.hasOwnProperty(x) && typeof result[x] != "function") {
                        if (result[x].Vendor == vendor) {
                            e = (result[x]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (e) {
                    e.Values.push(o);
                } else {
                    result.push({
                        Visible: true,
                        Vendor: vendor,
                        Values: [o]
                    });
                }
            });

            result.forEach(function (item, i) {
                item.Index = i;
                item.Values.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return a.Month - b.Month;
                });
            });
        } catch (e) {
            result = null;
        };

        return result;

    };
    var createChart = function (chartElement, cd) {
        var chartData = cd; //chart data is being passed in using cd via createChart function 
        //chart gives the location of the chart, 

        var chart = function (el, data) {
            var margin = {
                top: 20,
                right: 180,
                bottom: 50,
                left: 110

            };
            var elem = el;
            var chartEl = chartElement;
            var fillData = [];


            var defs,
                gs,
                height,
                line,
                maxDays,
                minDays,
                minValue,
                maxValue,
                x,
                xAxis,
                zoomBeh,
                y,
                yAxis;

            var initialiseData = function (dataValues) {
                minDays = d3.min(dataValues,
                    function (m) {
                        return d3.min(m.Values,
                            function (d) {
                                return d.Month;
                            });
                    });
                maxDays = d3.max(dataValues,
                    function (m) {
                        return d3.max(m.Values,
                            function (d) {
                                return d.Month;
                            });
                    });
                minValue = d3.min(chartData,
                    function (m) {
                        return d3.min(m.Values,
                            function (d) {
                                return d.Value;
                            });
                    });
                maxValue = d3.max(chartData,
                    function (m) {
                        return d3.max(m.Values,
                            function (d) {
                                return d.Value;
                            });
                    });
                console.log('min days: ' + minDays);
                console.log('max days: ' + maxDays);
                console.log('min value: ' + minValue);
                console.log('max value: ' + maxValue);

                dataValues.forEach(function (item) {
                    var nu = $.extend(true, {}, item);
                    nu.Values.push({ Month: maxDays, Value: minValue });
                    nu.Values.push({ Month: minDays, Value: minValue });
                    fillData.push(nu);
                });
            };
            //initialise scales
            var configSize = function () {
                if (isNaN(numberChecker) === true) {
                    numberChecker = $(chartEl).width();
                    width = numberChecker;

                }

                width = 750;

                height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
                x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([0, width])
                    .domain([minDays, maxDays]);

                y = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([height, 0])
                    .domain([minValue, maxValue]);

                $('.adjustmentZoom .tick text').attr('y', '25');
                //initialise axis
                xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .tickFormat(function (d, i) {
                        if (Math.floor(d) !== d) {
                        } else {
                            return moment(d).format("MMM YY");
                        }
                    })
                    .orient('bottom');


                yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .tickFormat(function (d) {
                        return d3.round(d, 3) + "%"
                    })
                    .orient('left');

                $('#clipper rect').attr('width', width);
                $('.zoom-panel').attr('width', width);



            };






            //the path generator for the line chart
            var initialise = function () {
                line = d3.svg.line()
                    .interpolate(
                        'cardinal')
                    .x(function (d) {
                        return x(d.Month);
                    })
                    .y(function (d) {
                        return y(d.Value);
                    });

                zoomBeh = d3.behavior.zoom()
                    .x(x)
                    .y(y)
                    .scaleExtent([
                        1,
                        500
                    ])
                    .on('zoom', zoomed);



                //elem is window
                svg = d3.select(elem).append('div').attr('id', 'scatter').append('svg')
                    .attr('width', '100%')
                    .attr('height', '100%')
                    .attr('viewBox', '0 0 1000 550')
                    .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
                    .append('g')
                    .attr("class", "line-container")
                    .attr('transform',
                        function () {
                            if (window.innerWidth > 650) {
                                var marginWidth = margin.left;

                            }
                            else if (window.innerWidth <= 650 && window.innerWidth > 549) {
                                var marginWidth = margin.left + 30;

                            }
                            else if (window.innerWidth <= 549) {
                                var marginWidth = margin.left + 50;

                            }
                            return 'translate(' + marginWidth + ',' + margin.top + ')'
                        }).call(zoomBeh).on("dblclick.zoom", null);









                svg.append('rect')
                    .attr('class', 'zoom-panel')
                    .attr('width', width)
                    .attr('height', height)
                .call(zoomBeh);

                svg.append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'x axis')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
                    .call(xAxis)
                    .selectAll('text');
                svg.append('text')
                    .attr('x', 400)
                    .attr('y', (height + 70))
                    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
                    .attr('class', 'xTitle')
                    .style('font-weight', '500')
                    .text('Date by month');
                svg.append('g').attr('class', 'y axis').attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)').style('text-anchor', 'end').call(yAxis);
                svg.append('text')
                    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
                    .attr('y', -100)
                    .attr('x', -200)
                    .attr('dy', '1em')
                    .attr('class', 'yTitle')
                    .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
                    .style('font-weight', '500')
                    .text('Share prices in percentage');



                //zoom.scaleExtent([
                //    1,
                //    moment(maxDays).diff(minDays, "months")
                //]);


            }





            //draw calls drawData which will draw the lines of the chart
            var draw = function () {
                var drawData = function (dat, className, baseFill, area) {

                    //var selection (supermarket)
                    var supermarket, supermarketEnter;
                    supermarket = svg.selectAll('.' + className)
                        .data(dat,
                            function (c) {
                                return c.Vendor;
                            });

                    //var new selection (supermarketEnter)
                    supermarketEnter = supermarket.enter()
                        .append('g')
                        .attr('class', className)
                        .attr('data-vendor', function(d) { return d.Vendor; })
                        .attr('width', width)
                        .attr('height', height);
                    supermarketEnter.append('path');

                    //update new selection

                    supermarketEnter.attr('clip-path', 'url(#clipper)').attr('class', 'line').attr('id', function (d) { return d.Vendor; });
                    supermarket.select('path')
                        .transition()
                        .attr('class', 'line-data')
                        .duration(500)
                        .attr('d',
                            function (d) {
                                return line(d.Values);
                            });

                    var path = supermarket.select('path')
                    .style('stroke', function (d, i) {
                        return (d.Visible ? baseFill(d.Index) : grayFill);

                    });
                    if (area) {
                        path.style('fill', function (d, i) { return (d.Visible ? baseFill(d.Index) : grayFill); });

                    }
                    supermarketEnter
                        .selectAll("circle")
                        .data(function (d) {
                            return d.Values;
                        })
                            .enter()
                            .append('circle')
                            .attr('class', 'datapoint')
                            .attr('r', 4)
                            .style('fill',
                                function (d, i, j) {
                                    return dat[j].Visible ? baseFill(j) : grayFill;
                                })
                            .attr('transform',
                            function (d) {
                                return 'translate(' + x(d.Month) + ',' + y(d.Value) + ')';
                            })
                            .on('mouseover',
                            function (d, i, j) {
                                d3.select('.tooltip').style('opacity', '1');
                                d3.select('.tooltip')
                                    .html(dat[j].Vendor +
                                        '<br/> (' +
                                        moment(d.Month).format("MMM YYYY") +
                                        ', ' +
                                        d.Value.toPrecision(2) +
                                        '% )')
                                    .style('left',
                                        function () {

                                            if (window.innerWidth >= 1200) {
                                                var newWidth = d3.event.pageX -
                                                    ($(chartEl).width() / 2) +
                                                    'px'
                                            } else if (window.innerWidth < 1200) {
                                                var newWidth = d3.event.pageX - ($(chartEl).width() / 10) + 'px'
                                            }

                                            return newWidth;
                                        })
                            .style('top', (d3.event.pageY) - 300 + 'px');


                            })
                            .on("mouseout",
                                function (d) {

                                    d3.select('.tooltip')
                                        .style('transition', '500')
                                        .style('opacity', 0)
                                        .style('color', d3.select(this).style('fill'));
                                });

                    supermarket.exit().remove();
                    supermarket.order();
                }

                svg.selectAll('.x.axis').call(xAxis);
                svg.selectAll('.y.axis').call(yAxis);


                drawData(chartData, 'supermarket', patterns, false);



            };

            var render = function () {
                configSize();
                draw();




            };

            //insertion of drawLegend into chart function so that this will draw as well as the lines of the chart.
            var drawLegend = function (dat, className) {


                //DATA JOIN
                //Join new data with old elements, if any.
                var supermarket, supermarketEnter;
                supermarket = svg.selectAll('legend_' + className)
                    .data(dat, function (c) { return c.Vendor; });

                //UPDATE
                //Update old elements as needed.
                supermarket.attr('class', 'update');



                //ENTER + UPDATE
                //After merging the entered elements with the update selection, apply operations to both.
                supermarketEnter = supermarket.enter().append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'legend_' + className)
                    .attr('data-vendor', function (d) { return d.Vendor; });
                supermarketEnter
                    .append('text')
                    .attr('class', 'supermarket-name')
                    .attr('data-vendor', function (d) { return d.Vendor + "-legend"; });//
                supermarket.select('text.supermarket-name')
                    .attr('x', width + 25)
                    .attr('y', function (d, i) { return (i * 1.25) * 20; })
                    .attr('dy', '.35em')
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.Vendor;
                    })
                    .on('click', function (d, i, j) {
                        dat[i].Visible = !dat[i].Visible;
                        var newOpacity = dat[i].Visible ? 1 : 0;

                        d3.select("[data-vendor='" + dat[i].Vendor + "']").style('opacity', newOpacity);
                    });
                supermarketEnter.append('rect')
                    .attr('class', 'supermarket-dot');
                supermarket.select('rect.supermarket-dot')
                    .attr('x', width + 10).attr('y', function (d, i) {
                        return ((i * 1.25) * 20) - 5;
                    })
                    .attr('width', 12)
                    .attr('height', 12)
                    .style('fill', function (d, i) {
                        return patterns(d.Index);

                    });

                //EXIT
                //Remove old elements as needed.
                supermarket.exit().remove();

                d3.select(elem).append('div').attr('class', 'tooltip').style('opacity', 0);

               return createChart().chart().initialise().zoomBeh.x(x);
            };

            var svgTransform = function (d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.Month) + "," + y(d.Value) + ")";
            };

            var lineTransform = function(d) {
                return line(d.Values);

            }



            var zoomed = function () {
                svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
                svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
                svg.selectAll(".datapoint").attr("transform", svgTransform);
                svg.selectAll(".line-data").attr("d", lineTransform); 
            };


            //insertion of drawLegend into chart function originally placed after configSize(); draw(); };


            var toggleLines = function () {
                var dat = $(this.closest("g")).data();
                var obj = chartData.find(function (item) { return item.Vendor === dat.vendor; });
                if (obj.Visible) {
                    obj.Visible = false;
                } else {
                    obj.Visible = true;
                }
                chartData.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a.Visible === b.Visible) return 0;
                    if (a.Visible && !b.Visible) return 1;
                    return -1;
                });
                draw();
            };


            initialiseData(data);
            configSize();
            initialise();
            draw();
            drawLegend(chartData, 'supermarket');
            tooltip();


            $('.adjustmentZoom .tick text').attr('y', '25');
            return {
                Draw: render

            };


        };

        var c = chart(chartElement, chartData);
        //draw draws the lines of the chart. chart function draws the space arou
        $(window).on("resize", function () {
            c.Draw();
            $('.adjustmentZoom .tick text').attr('y', '25');
        });

    }




    var initialiseElement = function () {
        categories.forEach(function (item) {
            $(".slidesIntroduction").append('<div class="">\
                    <div class="insight-chart chart tradingData ' + item.Name + '" style="' + item.Style + '">\
                    <h3 class="chartTitle" ><br />\All ' + item.Title + '</h3>\
                        <p style="' + item.TitleStyle + '">\
                            <br />\
                            ' + item.Text + '\
                        </p>\
                    </div>\
                <//div>');
        });
    };



    var renderInsightData = function () {
        initialiseElement();
        categories.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.DataValues) {
                createChart("." + item.Name, item.DataValues);
            }
        });
    };

    var startWork = function () {
        var catCount = 0;

        var startRequest = function () {
            App.Modules.ServerComms.PollForData({
                Url: url,
                Data: { src: categories[catCount].Name },
                Success: processResponse,
            });
        };

        var processResponse = function (response) {
            categories[catCount].DataValues = getValues(response);
            catCount++;
            if (catCount < categories.length) {
                startRequest();
            } else {
                renderInsightData();
                $(".spinner").removeClass("spinner");
            }
        };

        startRequest();
    };

    return {
        Name: "Introduction",
        Init: function () { },
        Start: startWork
    }

})());
```

Comment: code contains working line chart with zoom and tool tips.